# react component displaying in first render but not in the following re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react component that consists in an alert to which I am passing 2 props, (however these 2 props rarely change within this component)

```
const AlertPopUp = ({ severity, errors }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)
  console.log('show value of show state: ', show)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('gets here')
    const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
      // After 5 seconds set the show value to false
      setShow(false)
    }, 5000)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeId)
    }
  });

  console.log('errors ', errors)

  if (!errors)  return null
  if (show) 
    return (
      <>
        <Alert severity={severity}>
          {errors}
        </Alert>
      </>
    )
}
```

In the first render, the `Alert` shows up and after the expected 5 seconds the component disappears.

In the re-render, the `Alert` does not show up anymore, and from my debugging I assume it has to do to with the line `console.log('show value of show state: ', show)` which displays false in the re-render.

If I do a `setShow(true)` I run into an infinite loop of re-renders.

If I use a `useRef` to avoid the `useState` infinite loop the component doesn't re-render and therefore the `Alert` never displays.

If I try to set a key to the component `key=useId()`/ pass a counter , the state is still set to false whenever the parent component rerenders, looking like the component doesn't destroy and create again.

Please forgive me if I made any of my assumptions wrongly as I am far from being a react expert.

Could please anyone help me find a solution so that the `Alert` displays in every render of the alert component and disappears after the 5 seconds?

Comment: you mean it doesn't show up *next* time you want to show it?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava yes

Comment: The `useEffect` hook is missing the dependency array, so the effect will run any time the `AlertPopUp` component rerenders ***for any reason***. It seems the component works as expected first time it ***mounts***. When exactly, and under what conditions, do you want this component to render the `Alert` component?

Comment: `useId` solution should work if, if you are getting different `ids` from useid everytime. Does it not generate unique ids everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

From what I can understand of your post, the `AlertPopUp` component works without issue upon the initial mount and render. The problem is then how to retrigger the component to render the `Alert`.

## Solution

I suggest lifting state up and making the `AlertPopUp` a fully controlled component that also consumes an `onClose` callback to handle updating the `show` state.

Example:

```
const AlertPopUp = ({ show, severity = "error", errors, onClose }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
      // After 5 seconds set the show value to false
      onClose();
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeId);
    };
  });

  if (!errors) return null;
  if (show) {
    return (
      <Alert onClose={onClose} severity={severity}>
        {errors}
      </Alert>
    );
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const closeHandler = () => setShow(false);

return (
  ...

  {/* Just an example to trigger the alert to display */}
  <button type="button" onClick={() => setShow(true)}>
    Show Alert
  </button>

  <AlertPopUp
    {...{ errors, show, onClose: closeHandler }}
  />

  ...
);
```

Now when either the timeout expires ***or*** the user manually dismisses the alert the `onClose` callback is called and will update the `show` state in the ancestor to `false` and hide the `Alert` component.

[image: Edit react-component-displaying-in-first-render-but-not-in-the-following-re-render]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are never setting `show` back to `true`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem with your code. Let me explain, on initial render, show is true, so your alert component renders. But you also set show to false .Now when your props change , which causes a re-render but because show is still false , your alert component doesn’t re-render. So try this;  move your setTimeOut where you set setshow to false outside the useEffect ( it’s still going to run ) and then inside your useEffect , set show to true and also pass your props (errors and severity) into the array that useEffect takes as second argument so that when those props change , your useEffect will run setting show to true which will cause ur component to re-render and show being true , your alert renders .

Comment: this solution just re-renders the component one time after the other because it is inside the useEffect that render in each component re--render and as state is updated looks like it runs into an infinite loop

Comment: Try passing an empty array as second argument to useEffect to ensure it only runs once.

Comment: this continues returning an inifinite loop

Comment: could you please provide your proprosed code solution? and provide some explanation on why it should work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue essentially was:

1. Alert was not getting triggered after change of props (`severity` here)
2. `show` state was not getting set to `true` whenever props change

Here, I have simulated the prop change behaviour by a counter and therefore after every 10 sec, alert would pop-up.

**Solution:**

1. put `severity` in deps array
2. On every prop change `useEffect` will trigger and then set show as `true`.

```js
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Dummy Alert Component
const Alert = ({ severity, children }) => {
  alert(children);
  return null;
};

// Reusable AlertPopUp component with same props
const AlertPopUp = ({ severity, errors }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const timeId = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setShow(true);
    timeId.current = setTimeout(() => {
      // After 5 seconds set the show value to false
      setShow(false);
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeId.current);
    };
  }, [severity]);

  if (!errors) return null;
  if (show)
    return (
      <>
        {" "}
        <Alert severity={severity}>{errors}</Alert>{" "}
      </>
    );
};

// Component for simulating the behaviour
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  let counter = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter) {
      counter.current = setTimeout(() => {
        setCount(count + 1);
      }, 10000);
    }
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(counter.current);
    };
  }, [count]);

  console.log("this is count", count);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AlertPopUp severity={count} errors={`this is error: ${count}`} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Link to Implementation in Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hertz-gjiexc?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. You may need to use [key](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate#resetting-state-with-a-key) if you want the component to re-render. A link to the working code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-sound-6hx9p3?file=/src/App.js:196-575).

```
const AlertPopUp = ({ severity, errors }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
      // After 5 seconds set the show value to false
      setShow(false);
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeId);
    };
  });

  return !errors ? null : show && <Alert severity={severity}>{errors}</Alert>;
};
```

Usage:

```
<AlertPopUp key={key} severity={severity} errors={error}/>
```